# Data transmission from Unity (C#) to Python and vice versa using TCP sockets

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, tcpsocket

So I am relatively new to Unity and socket communications.
I have a unity scene from which I want to send some robot position (Vector3) and some other float data to python over tcp socket.
I also want to send some control actions (float data) from python to Unity.

On python side I have:

```
import socket
import time

class connect_class(object):
    
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 25001
    sock = []

    def connect(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
        except Exception: 
            print("Connection Error, Check if Unity scene is running.")

class communication_class(object):
    connect_cl = connect_class()
    connect_cl.connect()
    sock = connect_cl.sock

    def receive(self):
        self.receivedData = self.sock.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8") 
        print(self.receivedData)

cl = communication_class()
cl.receive()
```

The result I am getting is:
When I call the `receive()` for the first time.

> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}

However If I call `receive()` multiple times after that, the same data is just aggregated, as shown below.

> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.728967666625978,"z":-23.946182250976564}]}
> {"robot_pos":[{"x":-7.992547035217285,"y":21.72896766662

I would like to receive only the complete vector only once whenever I call receive.

On the Unity (C#) side I have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

public class comm : MonoBehaviour
{
    Thread mThread;
    public string connectionIP = "127.0.0.1";
    public int connectionPort = 25001;
    IPAddress localAdd;
    TcpListener listener;
    TcpClient client;
    Vector3 receivedPos = Vector3.zero;
    public GameObject robot;
    public Vector3 robot_pos;

    

    bool running;

    public string SaveToString()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
    }

    public class JsonData
    {
        public List<Vector3> robot_pos = new List<Vector3>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = receivedPos; //assigning receivedPos in SendAndReceiveData()
        robot_pos = robot.transform.position;

    }

    private void Start()
    {
        robot = GameObject.Find("robot");
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(GetInfo);
        mThread = new Thread(ts);
        mThread.Start();
    }

    void GetInfo()
    {
        localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(connectionIP);
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, connectionPort);
        listener.Start();

        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

        running = true;
        while (running)
        {
            SendData();
            //SendAndReceiveData();
        }
        listener.Stop();
    }

    void SendData()
    {   
        
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(nwStream) { AutoFlush = true };
        var testData = new JsonData();
        testData.robot_pos = new List<Vector3>()
        {
            robot_pos
        };
        var result = JsonUtility.ToJson(testData);

        //---Sending Data to Host----
        sw.WriteLine(result);
        //string data = robot_pos.ToString();
        //sw.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    }
}
```

I am not sure how to just receive complete current robot position once per `receive()` call.

I would appreciate any help or if there are any other better ways to do it.

I tried to use `streamwriter.flush()` however it also dosent work.

Comment: Hi, tcp guarantees order of packets but isn't message based. This means you have to implement your own message handling mechanism on top e.g. determine what data forms a cohesive message and what data belongs to the next message. If you want to rely on TCP, that's the way to go. If you are open to using the WebSocket protocol, it does exactly that:)

Comment: There are basically two possible messaging protocols for TCP: a) use a dedicated end of message indicator (e.g. a string like `"###"` or in your case `}` and simply read until you reach that symbol... or you prepend the amount of bytes to receive, read until you have the correct amount of bytes and then pass it on and parse the data

Comment: In general: if you are interested in a single vector (3 floats -> 12bytes) why pack this into a **list** which is further nested in a JSON? This is a lot of networking overhead. Indeed you would actually know exactly how many bytes to receive (12) if you just used a binary protocol instead of strings

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issue is here:

```
while (running)
{
    SendData();
    //SendAndReceiveData();
}
```

That's just going to send the same data in a loop forever.

If you only want it to send the position once when the listener connects, then drop the while loop and just SendData once and then close the socket and wait for another connection.